# Copy and paste commits in Git

Tags: git, github

Imagine a commit Tree as such:

```
 ----master--------commit_1--------commit_3--------commit_5---------->
               \
  'new branch'  \ ----------commit_2---------commit_4-->
```

I want to be able to take 'commit 2', and commit it to master, WITHOUT merging the new branch, or reverting all other commits on the new branch.

My first thought was to stash 'commit_2', switch to master, then git pop, but I don't know if that will work.

Comment: you can try cherry picking

Comment: Never heard of that before, and it was exactly what i needed